# Use node.js to save json file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, save, fs

I am very new to Node server/javacsript. So I am sorry if this might be stupid 
question/topic.

I intended to create a very simple solution to open JSON file, load to list, and save it back to my local disk (running node.js server).

Could you please help me out, what I am doing wrong? I am running app in browser using react.

index.js containing

```
  var fs = require('fs');
  var fileName = './test.json';
  var file = require('./test.json');

  alert(file.name + " " + file.age);

  file.name = "Peter";

  alert(file.name + " " + file.age);
  fs.writeFile('./test.json', JSON.stringify(file), function (err) {
    if (err) return alert(err);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(file));
    alert('writing to ' + fileName);
  });
```

Before I was not even able to open JSON file. I needed to include this property into the webpack config file.

```
node: {
    fs: 'empty'
}
```

Now I am able to open JSON file, change it virtually, but unable to save it.
In chrome developer tools, it prints "*fs.writeFile is not a function*" into console.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you included the property in your webpack config

```
node: {
  fs: 'empty'
}
```

You told webpack that the module `fs` should just be an empty object. You can confirm this by simply putting a `console.log(fs)` in your file to see it is indeed empty.

Beyond that, `fs` is not going to work in your browser. `fs` expects the node.js runtime (which includes non-JavaScript things in order to make it work), not your browser's runtime.

If you want a user to save a file, you'll have to use a browser based saving solution. You won't be able to just arbitrarily write files like that outside of something like your browser's local storage.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. And in case I'd like to store some values, like save values from a table when user changes something, should I probably use AJAX, right? Or what would you advice?

Comment: Yeah. Some kind of HTTP API using AJAX on in the browser would work fine.